# duration {lubridate}: Can durations be negative?

Tags: r, datetime, time, lubridate

Every documentation I've read seems to indicate that durations can be negative in *lubridate* 1.7.4, including the examples provided with the R Documentation:

```
> duration(-1, "days")
> duration(day = -1)
```

[This one bugfix back in 2009](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/35) says something similar with example output:

```
> new_duration(secs = -1, mins = -1, hours = -1)
[1] "-1 hours, -1 minutes and -1 seconds"
```

But when I run `duration(-1, "days")`, R returns:

```
[1] "86400s (~1 days)"
```

What's the deal?

Comment: How can a duration be negative?  It doesn't make logical sense.

Comment: @thc any time an expression `a - b` makes sense, negative values of `b` also necessarily make sense.  `lubridate` allows subtracting durations from times, so it makes sense to allow those durations to be negative and to support a negation operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they can be negative. From a reading of the source code, this is an artifact of the print method for the `Duration` class. Inspecting the object shows that it stays negative despite not displaying as such, and behaves like a negative number as it should, as shown below.

I think the culprit is line 102 of the [source code here](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/blob/master/R/durations.r). The `format.Duration`function calls `abs` when printing a `Duration`. I guess this is intended behaviour, though you'd have to take it up with the developers for the reasoning (probably because people tend to understand durations as positive.)

EDIT: in [Dec 2019](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/commit/d4677069d225e0aa78cc66055fa5c4a1447064e4) the print method was changed to show negative durations with a leading -, so this should only happen on older version of lubridate now.

```r
library(lubridate)
neg <- duration(-1)
pos <- duration(2)
neg + pos
#> [1] "1s"
unclass(neg)
#> [1] -1
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is still an issue when you print it, but the duration works fine when negative:

```
date <- mdy("7/8/17")
date - duration(10, "days")
# [1] "2017-06-28"
date + duration(-10, "days)
# [1] "2017-06-28"
```

The duration is a class with `.Data` slot containing the duration in seconds, and you can check to confirm that it's indeed negative:

```
duration(-10, "days")@.Data
# [1] -864000
duration(-10, "days")@.Data / 3600 / 24 # to get the days:
# [1] -10
```